# Is it possible to fix Takahashi?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, is there any way to "fix" Takahashi (the noodle Protectron in Diamond City) so that he can speak English to the Sole Survivor? Or is he broken forever?

Comment: I haven't found anything saying that this is possible.  Perhaps a mod maybe, but thats it.

Comment: Pretty sure he's broken forever, but I can't prove it without access to the game's code.

Comment: Nan-ni shimasho-ka?

Comment: @Vemonus - mo ichi do onegai shimasu. eigo kudasai

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I checked the wiki, however the page on Takahashi provides no indication to whether or not he can be fixed, just that Mayor McDonough will not allow it. [Takahashi's wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Takahashi).

One discussion I found on steam postulates that maybe hacking into, and then moving Takahashi to another location outside of Diamond city could fix him. However it seems all this accomplishes is that Takahashi will no longer sell you noodles, from this [discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/494632506573063127/).

So, according to experiments and gameplay so far, no he cannot be fixed.